# PHP shows outdated MySQLnd version

Tags: centos, php, webserver, cpanel, whm

PHP is using MySQLnd 5.0.12-dev and we cannot figure out how to get it to use the newer versions. The server has MySQLnd 5.6.40 installed but we cannot figure out how to get it to use it. We've been working on this for 2 or 3 days now and searches on the issue tend to end up on people asking about php version 5.5 instead of being related to MySQLnd.

We're running CentOS, WHM, CPanel, Apache, PHP 7.2

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Tried updating PHP, uninstalling and reinstalling PHP.
WHMCpanel shows its up to date but websites are still using 5.0.12 instead of the much more recent 5.6.40.